# Convert all white pixels in the image into black pixels

Tags: python, graphics, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, opencv

I have this image `rand-walk-2.png`

[image: rand-walk-2.png]

I would like to convert all the white pixels to black pixels, so that there is a picture of a *red random walk* over a black background, this means I cannot just invert the colors of image. My current code simply finds the white pixels and set them to black:

```
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ImageOps    
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imsave
import cv2


in_path  = 'rand-walk-2.png'
out_path = 'rand-walk-trial.png'


Image = cv2.imread(in_path)
Image2 = np.array(Image, copy=True)

white_px = np.asarray([255, 255, 255])
black_px = np.asarray([0  , 0  , 0  ])

(row, col, _) = Image.shape

for r in xrange(row):
    for c in xrange(col):
        px = Image[r][c]
        if all(px == white_px):
            Image2[r][c] = black_px

imsave(out_path, Image2)
```

But it produces this:

[image: rand-walk-trial.png]

for some reason I cannot explain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is that module [skimage](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imsave) (in your case function `skimage.io.imsave`) uses RGB color sequence, whereas OpenCV (in your case function `cv2.imread`) [notoriously](http://www.learnopencv.com/why-does-opencv-use-bgr-color-format/) uses BGR color sequence. So blue and red colors become swapped with your script.

Two solutions for you would be to either convert the image to RGB directly after reading:

```
Image = cv2.imread(in_path)
Image = cv2.cvtColor(Image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Or to save the output image with cv2:

```
cv2.imwrite(out_path, Image2)
```

Result:

[image: Red random walk on black background]

---

Another solution, which gives much nicer output, is simply inverting your image:

```
Image = cv2.imread(in_path)
Image = cv2.bitwise_not(Image)
cv2.imwrite(out_path, Image)
```

Result:

[image: Beautiful cyan random walk on black background]

Or, if you still want red color, you could invert, remove green channel and swap blue and red:

```
Image = cv2.imread(in_path)
Image = cv2.bitwise_not(Image)
b,g,r = cv2.split(Image)
z = np.zeros_like(g)
Image = cv2.merge((z,z,b))
cv2.imwrite(out_path, Image)
```

Result:

[image: Beautiful red random walk on black background]

Comment: I'm guessing the parts that still look white are just very light red colors that appear white agains the background?

Comment: Indeed. You might be better off by simply inverting the image. See above for example.

Comment: beautify.  exactly what I wanted.