# Convert White Pixels to Black in OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to convert the white background of the input image into black using python OpenCV.But all the white pixels are not completely getting converted to black. I have attached the input and output images.

Input Image :

[image: Input Image in the window]

Output Image:

[image: Output Image in the Window]

I have used the following code for conversion:

```
img[np.where((img==[255,255,255]).all(axis=2))] = [0,0,0];
```

What should I do?

Comment: detect the elliptical region and mask all outside of it

Comment: or for example you could first mask a "near white" image and then only use those pixels as background that are connected to the image border.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this has already been answered. I have a coded python solution for you.

Firstly I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49888538/convert-all-white-pixels-in-the-image-into-black-pixels) explaining how to remove white pixels.

The Result:

[image: result]

Another Test img:

[image]
[image]

**Edit**
This is a way better and shorter method. I looked into it after @ZdaR commented on looping over an images matrix.

[**Updated Code**]

```
img = cv2.imread("Images/test.pnt")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

img[thresh == 255] = 0

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
erosion = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations = 1)

cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("image", erosion)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19666626/replace-all-elements-of-python-numpy-array-that-are-greater-than-some-value)

[**Old Code**]

```
img = cv2.imread("Images/test.png")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 240, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

white_px = np.asarray([255, 255, 255])
black_px = np.asarray([0, 0, 0])

(row, col) = thresh.shape
img_array = np.array(img)

for r in range(row):
    for c in range(col):
        px = thresh[r][c]
        if all(px == white_px):
            img_array[r][c] = black_px

kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (5, 5))
erosion = cv2.erode(img_array, kernel, iterations = 1)

cv2.namedWindow('image', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.imshow("image", erosion)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Other Sources used:
[OpenCV Morphological Transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html)

Comment: While using OpenCV its is never a good idea to iterate the image matrix pixel by pixel using nested for loop in Python, using Numpy syntax is always preferable.

Answer (score 1):

I think not all the "white" pixels in the image are [255,255,255]. Instead, make a threshold. Try [220,220,220] and above and convert them to [0, 0, 0].

Comment: this might affect  the bright yellow region in the centre!

Comment: conversion to hsv may help in segmenting the image

Comment: As Jeru Luke said, the threshold [220,220,220] is affecting the yellow region in some images.

Comment: Use hit and trial. Try [230, 230, 230] next, if it still affects yellow, then go for [235, 235, 235] and so on.

Comment: This approach does not scale well. Whatever you set the threshold to, *any* occurrence inside the image will also be affected. The question is badly specified – OP does *not* want **all** lighter pixels converted to black, but only those *around* the main image.