# How to change an image with a transparent background to white background using opencv

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I'm trying my hand at locating contours in opencv, and am using an image with a transparent background. After loading the image into memory and showing the image, the transparent background has been recolored into black and white rectangular shapes surrounding the focus of the picture.

```
image = cv.imread('C:/Users/H/Desktop/overhead.png')

cv.namedWindow('image', cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.imshow('image', image)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

Is the code that I'm currently using

Instead of having black pixels surrounding the image, there are several large white blocks(which are being detected as a contour).

Answer (score 1):

[Convert White Pixels to Black in OpenCV python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51347194/convert-white-pixels-to-black-in-opencv-python)

I found an appropriate solution.

However now the ~circular shape in the upper right is not being detected. All 3 rectangles are found. [tresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mYKY.png)

```
gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
thresh = cv.threshold(blurred, 103, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

cnts = cv.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv.RETR_EXTERNAL,
cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

# loop over the contours
for c in cnts:
# compute the center of the contour
M = cv.moments(c)
cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])

# draw the contour and center of the shape on the image
cv.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
cv.circle(image, (cX, cY), 7, (255, 255, 255), -1)
cv.putText(image, "center", (cX - 20, cY - 20),
cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)

# show the image
cv.namedWindow('image', cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.imshow('image', image)
cv.waitKey(0)
```